# recaptcha v2 -> enterprise server side verification equivalent?

Tags: recaptcha, recaptcha-enterprise

I'm trying to convert a v2 recaptcha flow to use the enterprise version. What is the equivalent to the server side call to `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify`?

If I try to send the same or similar POST request to `https://recaptchaenterprise.googleapis.com` or `https://recaptchaenterprise.googleapis.com/<project path>`, I get a 404 back.

There does not appear to be a matching v1 or v1beta1 endpoint for siteverify -- at least not that I've found in any of the docs or in the official recaptcha node.js library. What am I missing here?

Comment: For reference, this is the server side pattern we are following for v2 https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify

Comment: I'd recommend you to file issue on Google's [IssueTracker](https://issuetracker.google.com) if you're not able to find enough guidance at the official documentation or if some features doesn't work as you expected.

Comment: Got an answer at length from google support, but never heard anything via that issue tracker Wojtek. I appreciate the attempted help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct equivalent to the previously recommended verification call in the enterprise version (the call to `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify`).

If you want to mimic this server side verification flow, you must create a new assessment for the checkbox token and make a judgement based on that score yourself.

Comment: Direct link to documentation https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/create-assessment

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have found a solution by now. But for those still looking

if you configure your request like this you'll get what you want:
`https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=${recaptchaSecretKey}&response=${recaptchaToken}`;

where secret is 'The shared key between your site and reCAPTCHA.'
And response is 'The user response token provided by the reCAPTCHA client-side integration on your site.'.